# silence those dreaded inbox crickets

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, idiomatic-language

I just saw an [article](https://www.inc.com/kat-boogaard/is-your-email-being-ignored-try-one-of-these-tactics.html) titled "*4 Ways to React When Your Email Keeps Being Ignored*". There is a smaller sentence beneath the main title, it says

> Want to silence those dreaded inbox **crickets**? These four strategies can help.

I am confused about this sentence and really do not know what the authors' mean.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of **crickets** it's a metaphor, maybe you have seen it in a movie.

According to Your Dictionary

**[crickets](https://www.yourdictionary.com/crickets)**

> (US slang, humorous or derisive) **absolute silence; no communication**.
>   Derived from the cinematic metaphor of chirping crickets at night,
>   signaling (otherwise) complete quiet. 
> May be used alone or in
>   metaphorically descriptive phrases.
>
> *Since then, I've received no response. Not a word. Just... crickets.*

Your **email being ignored** is represented as **crickets** chirping in the night because you're getting **no response** at all in your inbox.

Comment: Thank you so much Rubio, now I got it